# Selection query returning value 0 for not satisfying the condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the `count(*)` as some variable with grouping by products based on some condition.

If that condition is not satisfied I want the query to return 0 for count variable value with that product.

I am using MySQL database and trying to use it in SAS, here is my query:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS common_mtrl, product AS product2 
    FROM join_mkt_sort A, support_mtrl B  
   WHERE support_mtrl_ind >= 1
         AND A.EKEY = B.SKEY 
         AND A.PKEY = B.SKEY
GROUP BY product
```

I want the query to assign `0` to variable `common_mtrl` for the products not meeting the condition.

Comment: [Welcome to SO, don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use this site](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: Which table is `product` on? Do you have a table that holds the details of all products?

Comment: Which "condition" are you worried about the product not satisfying?  The join or the support_mtrl_ind >= 1?

Comment: Gordon's answer worked for me.

Comment: @user2542275 then don't forget to mark it as the right answer. [**See how here.**](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your join.  Assuming all the rows you want are in the "A" table, you can join them like this:

```
select count(B.SKEY) as common_mtrl, product as product2
from join_mkt_sort A left outer join
     support_mtrl B  
     on A.EKEY = B.SKEY and A.PKEY = B.SKEY and
        support_mtrl_ind >=1 
group by product;
```

The `left outer join` keeps all the rows in the first table, even if there are no matches.  The `count()` counts the number of matches.

Comment: He didn't specify which "condition" he was worried about satisfying.  Your answer handles the case if the JOIN is his condition.  Mine handles the case if support_mtrl_ind >= 1 is his condition.

Comment: @BillGregg . . . This handles both.  The comparison is in the `on` clause, so all rows from `A` will be aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(case when support_mtrl_ind >=1 then 1 else 0 end) as common_mtrl,
       product as product2 
from join_mkt_sort A
    ,support_mtrl B  
where A.EKEY = B.SKEY and A.PKEY = B.SKEY
group by product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(b.skey),0) common_mtrl
     , product product2 
  FROM join_mkt_sort A
  LEFT
  JOIN support_mtrl B  
    ON A.EKEY = B.SKEY 
   AND A.PKEY = B.SKEY
   AND support_mtrl_ind >= 1 -- not sure which table this comes from
 GROUP 
    BY product
```

Answer (score 0):

check the condition if count is 0

```
 set @count int=0 set @result int select @count=count(*) as
 common_mtrl,product as product2 from join_mkt_sort A,support_mtrl B  
            where support_mtrl_ind >=1 
            and A.EKEY = B.SKEY and A.PKEY = B.SKEY
            group by product if(@count=0) set @result=0
```